# Get filter values in kendo grid ui

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I have kendo grid as

```
<kendo-grid
    [data]="gridData"
    [pageSize]="state.take"
    [skip]="state.skip"
    [sort]="state.sort"
    [filter]="state.filter"
    filterable="menu"
    (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
>
```

and in component.ts file

```
    public dataStateChange(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
    this.state = state;
    // get filter values here 

}
```

I want to get the filter values and field names in above function and pass them to api for server side filtering  but unable to extract the values from state.

Is there any way to extract fields and values from state object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitive variant

```
import { isCompositeFilterDescriptor } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
....
const filterValues = state.filter.filters.map(f => isCompositeFilterDescriptor(f) ? f.filters :[f] ).reduce((p,n) => p.concat(n), []);
```

But you should check "logic" field, see https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/api/CompositeFilterDescriptor/

Comment: Property 'filters' does not exist on type 'CompositeFilterDescriptor | FilterDescriptor'.
  Property 'filters' does not exist on type 'FilterDescriptor'.
any

Comment: First answer was in JavaScript. Updated code for TypeScript checks. Full code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1bjdzf